# how do pertinent diff with html, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, string, diff

I used this lib to do my diff : https://johnresig.com/files/jsdiff.js

but I have a problem now using html and not only text.

My use case (exemple) :

```
diffString('my first text', '<p>my first <strong>text</strong></p>')
```

return :

```
<del>my </del><ins><p>my </ins> first <del>text</del><ins><strong>text</strong></p></ins>
```

How can I ignore adding unvisible html like `<p>` but keep the diff on `<strong>` add ?

(maybe someone know what lib is used by stackoverflow?!)

Comment: What would be the desired output?

Comment: `<p>my first <del>text</del><ins><strong>text</strong></ins></p>`